# NDSolve does not correctly evaluate If combined when using replacement rules

Tags: differential-equations, functions, evaluation

I have reduced my problem to the following example where NDSolve produces the error:

> "NDSolve::nlnum: The function value {x[t]} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {t, x[t], NDSolve`s$907226[t]} = {2., 5., 1}. >>"

```
tr = s[t] /. s[t] -> x[t]
ts = NDSolve[{x'[t] == If[x[t] < 20, 2, tr], x[0] == 3}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. ts], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

In contrast, removing the if condition leads to a working `NDSolve`, but certainly not to the initially expected solution:

```
tr = s[t] /. s[t] -> x[t]
ts = NDSolve[{x'[t] == tr, x[0] == 3}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. ts], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Furthermore, not using replacement rules (Variable `tr`) works flawlessly and gives the expected result. Why is that so?

```
ts = NDSolve[{x'[t] == If[x[t] < 20, 2, x[t]], x[0] == 3}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. ts], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

My guess is that there is something off with the order of evaluation Mathematica uses, but I couldn't find any applicable examples or explanation. What is the culprit here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it is a matter of the order of evaluation. `If` has the attribute `HoldRest`, so you must evaluate `tr` explicitly in its argument list.

```
tr = s[t] /. s[t] -> x[t];
ts = NDSolve[{x'[t] == If[x[t] < 20, 2, Evaluate @ tr], x[0] == 3}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. ts], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]